# Django Template Variables in static path

Tags: python, django

I have a template where I need to access a directory based on the user's fields.

The code looks like this:

```
{% with user.client.company as company %}
{% static 'uploads/{{ company }}' as files %}
{% endwith %}
```

I also tried:

```
{% static 'uploads/{% user.client.company %}' as files %}
```

How can I achieve this?  I want the folder name to be equal to user.client.company but right now I get an error like:

Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endwith' for the first one and

Invalid block tag: 'static' for the second

Obviously I am doing it wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

It was pointed out I should use media rather than static.  But even so, I am unsure how to dynamically set the path based on the user's parameters.

Comment: Do you need `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top?

Comment: Why you storing user files in static? Why not media?

Comment: Thanks that hepled a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember to load you statics!!

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Comment: I added load staticfiles and it helped but I still get an error.

Comment: I was able to use `{% with '{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}/uploads/{{ user.client.company }}' as filedir %}` and it worked, is there a way to avoid needing {% endwith %}?

Comment: You're doing something a little strange here. usually you would use the static to implant the directory somewhere in your code when you need it. Not putting it in another template

Comment: I'm using the media directory now.  Still having trouble displaying the files but this problem was fixed